# Prevent 2d array to mutate, javascript

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an array which I want stay the same until I say otherwise. How do I prevent it from changing?

```
var orgArr = [[1,1], [2,2]];


function modArr(arr){
  arr[0][0] = 5;
  return arr;
}

modArr(orgArr);
console.log(orgArr); // It has changed
```

https://jsfiddle.net/50e6k7mc/

I tried some with immutable (which I added to the fiddle).

Something like

```
var orgArr = Immutable.List([[1,1],[2,2]])
```

Then using `toArray()`. But I cant get it to work.

Comment: Dude, why did you delete your previous question? I answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modifying function you need to convert first from Immutable , modify and then convert back to Immutable

```
arr=arr.toArray();
//.... modify arr
//....
arr= arr.fromJS(arr);
```

here is the updated code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/zvhp5k91/